# &error error - iOS dev

Tags: xcode, video, ios4

I am trying to create an AVCaptureSession. I based my code on the WWDC 2011 video, number 419.

I have the following line which is exactly the same as the code in the WWDC 2011 video and it also identical to code here http://www.bardecode.com/en/knowledge-base/214-detailed-description-of-work-around-for-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-problem-in-ios-41.html

```
    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                    error:&error];
```

But Xcode says that the &error is the use of an undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you've not defined the NSError `error` variable, that you're providing the address of when you use `&error`.

If you define the variable via...

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

...on the line before, all should be well.

As a bit of an explanation, if you look at the signature for the [AVCaptureDeviceInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceInput_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  deviceInputWithDevice:error: method you'll see the following:

```
+ (id)deviceInputWithDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device error:(NSError **)outError
```

In other words, this method expects the address of an NSError pointer variable to be provided as the `ourError` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Why isn't that included in the video and the sample code?

Comment: @SamB Looks like the author missed it out of their blog - the code as provided would always throw the error you're encountering. (I've not see the WWDC session video, so can't comment - perhaps the variable is defined in a previous video, etc.)